# How to get the first element of a SimpleXML object?

Tags: php, simplexml

`$xml` is a `SimpleXML` object.

```
print_r($xml->Title);
```

outputs `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => K&H 3093 Extreme Weather Kitty Pad with Fleece Cover )`

How do I access the first element?

```
print_r($xml->Title[0]);
```

outputs nothing!

Comment: That returns: SimpleXMLElement Object ( )

Comment: Cast to string ? `(string) $xml->Title`

Comment: SimpleXMLElement does not require `var_dump` or `print_r` to understand it, but reading the manual: [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) because it's so simple that it's so magic, that `print_r` and `var_dump` don't show you the picture *unless*  you've fully understood how `print_r` and `var_dump` work (or better say: not work) with **SimpleXMLElement**.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try

```
echo (string) $xml->Title;
```

You have to cast it as a string.

Comment: Simple and accurate answer. Thanks!